# Search in datatable and add the row result to another datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have two dataTables, one contain book titles and description filled from database and another will conatain the rows that are search result, keyword value is a variable.

I want to search the the first datatable, if the title or the description contain the variable, if yes I want to add the row to the new DataTable.

I tried the following code but it is not working,I get exception on results, and if I search a exact variable for title I get nothing in gridview.

```
DataTable books = new DataTable();
DataTable searchresults = new DataTable();
DataRow[] results;

 foreach (var v in keywordsarray)
 {
    results = books.Select("BookTitle like '"+v+"'or BookDescription like'"+v+"'");
 }

foreach (DataRow v in results)
{
    searchresults.ImportRow(v);
}

  //the grid view
 search.DataSource = searchresults;
 search.DataBind();
```

Comment: What is the exact exception and what line of code is causing it?  If you add the message you are seeing it would be helpful.

Comment: EvaluateException Error in Like operator: the string pattern 'System.String[]' is invalid when I select rows to results. And when I try to select exact value, the gridview don't show the result?

Comment: Based on that exception, it looks like 'v' is being recognized as a string array, not a string.  What happens if you change your loop to 'foreach(string v in keywordsarray)'?  Please add your keywordsarray variable declaration so we can see what type it is.

Comment: I get invalidcastexception unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Yep, that's your problem.... KeywordsArray is actually an array of arrays, or a nested array. You might have that declaration screwed up...Add the declaration so we can see.  Although the declaration is likely the problem you could always do 'foreach(var v in keywordsarray){ foreach(string s in v){ results = books.Select("BookTitle like '"+s+"'or BookDescription like'"+s+"'");}}'.  It should be noted that you are also setting the results variable multiple times in the loop, but you are not using it in the loop.  You will only see the last results because all the others are abandonded

Comment: keywordsarray is arraylist that contains the keywords

Comment: I think when you post a question you should post in with all the required details like in this case the declarations. So it will be easier for one who wishes to suggest.

Comment: You might want to use a List<string> instead of an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating `clone i.e. the structure of source datatable` before importing row into `destination datatable`.
Here is code how you could achieve this:

```
DataTable books = new DataTable();
DataRow[] results = default(DataRow[]); //initialized with default
string[] keywordsarray = new string[] { "a", "b" }; //example

books.Columns.Add("BookTitle"); //example added column
books.Columns.Add("BookDescription"); //example added column
books.AcceptChanges();

books.Rows.Add("abc", "def"); //example added row
books.Rows.Add("a", "c");   //example added row

//fill books datatable from database 

DataTable dtSearchResult = books.Clone();   //copy structure from source datatable

foreach (var v in keywordsarray)
{
    results = books.Select("BookTitle like '%" + v + "%' or BookDescription like '%" + v + "%'");

    foreach (DataRow dr in results)
    {
        //must be criteria here to check for duplicate rows in dtSearchResult.
        dtSearchResult.ImportRow(dr);
    }
}          

dtSearchResult.AcceptChanges();

 //the grid view
search.DataSource = dtSearchResult;
search.DataBind();
```

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of his exception.

Comment: Yes you are right missing % is not raising exception. I have updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you need to get your code to look like in order to get the data and avoid exceptions:

```
List<string> keywordsarray = new List<string>();

/*do something to fill your list with the keyword data*/

DataTable books = new DataTable();
DataTable searchresults = new DataTable();
DataRow[] results;

 foreach (string keyword  in keywordsarray)
 {
    results = books.Select("BookTitle like '"+keyword+"' or BookDescription like'"+keyword+"'");
    foreach (DataRow dr in results)
    {
       searchresults.ImportRow(dr);
    }
 }
 //the grid view
 search.DataSource = searchresults;
 search.DataBind();
```

If you want to have non-exact matches you will need to add the %'s to the select as pointed out in the other post:

```
results = books.Select("BookTitle like '%"+keyword+"%' or BookDescription like'%"+keyword+"%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using arraylist why not use something like:

```
foreach (string str in keywordsarray) 
 { 
    //use str in this case, which may resolve the exception 
 }
```